# EmberJS Invalid or Unexpected token without further information

Tags: npm, ember.js

I actually did nothing. I just wrote one line of CSS and since then its like that. I even tried to remove the whole CSS file I was working in, but it still does not work. Here you have the .log file:

```
ERROR Summary:

  - broccoliBuilderErrorStack: [undefined]
  - code: [undefined]
  - codeFrame: [undefined]
  - errorMessage: Invalid or unexpected token
  - errorType: [undefined]
  - location:
    - column: [undefined]
    - file: [undefined]
    - line: [undefined]
  - message: Invalid or unexpected token
  - name: SyntaxError
  - nodeAnnotation: [undefined]
  - nodeName: [undefined]
  - originalErrorMessage: [undefined]
  - stack: <path>\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:108
    EnvironmentPlugin: (


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
```

And I don't know who wrote this error logging method, but it is useless. I cannot tell what happened, since I didn't do anything except writing one line of CSS code.

Comment: could you *show* this line of CSS

Comment: Try clearing out your cache and dist folder and rerunning `ember s`.

Comment: @NicholasJohn16 THANK YOU!! I deleted everything in the dist folder and it is now working again. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone also having this issue and stumbled across this Question:
Try clearing the dist folder --> It worked for me.